# portrait to landscape in android

Tags: android, android-layout, landscape-portrait

I have three `Activities` in a `ActivityGroup`.

1. Activity1 in portrait mode then I click on button to move to Activity2.
2. Now  I change portrait mode to Landscape mode in Activity2 it switch to Activty1 in landscape mode.

I want when I am in Activity2 in portrait mode and switch to landscape in Activity2 it must be in Activity2 in landscape mode only.

I have all layouts in both folders layout and layout-land.

Comment: Code is same as we do in all xml and activity. Nothing different in code. I put an xml in the layout-land.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix the screen orientation of your activity

```
<activity android:name="com.example.TestActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait"> </activity>
```